# On form submit, render another form using AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin

I have a simple search form and on submit, I want to render another form with email text field and submit button using AJAX.

The initial form is part of rails_admin custom action and I want to carry the search params to second form as well.

```
javascript:
  $(".index_collection_link").hide()
= form_tag "/admin/sample/search_action”, class: "form-group", method: "get", :remote=>"true"
  .row
    .col-xs-12
      .col-xs-5
        .search
          = "Search:"
        =text_field_tag 'search',"" ,class: "form-control pull-right"
      .col-xs-4
        = submit_tag "Search", class: "btn btn-info"
```

On submit of this form I want to render another form with email input field:

```
javascript:
  $(".index_collection_link").hide()
= form_tag "/admin/send_emailf", class: "form-group", method: "get"
  .row
    .col-xs-12
      .col-xs-5
        .search style= "float:left;padding-top:5px;"
          = "Email "
        =email_field_tag 'email',"" ,class: "form-control pull-right"
      .col-xs-4
        = submit_tag "Send", class: "btn btn-info”
```

I have tried `respond_to` and render :partial method to render the second form. It shows in console that file has been rendered but on front end it stays on the search form.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The other way of handling this kind of functionality is by using js.erb.

create a file as search_action.js.erb and then you can render partial as and putting the html code of another form in that partial using rails' `j render` inside `append()` method.

Comment: Thanks @GaganGupta . I tried going by the default way in rails using remote true. But then used Ajax conventional way using which I was able to resolve my issue.